# Monitor.TryEnter returns false when object is not locked

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, circuit-breaker

I'm implementing circuit breaker on our service. It's quite standard Circuit Breaker except the fact that it wraps all the actions in timeout so it also breaks the circuit when too many timeouts occur.
When Circuit Breaker turns Half-Open state I'm using `MonitorTryEnter` method to ensure only one thread executes the action ( to check if service recovered ). Please find the snippet below ( this is a code executed during Half-Open state):

EDIT ( pasted whole function code )

```
public async Task<T> ExecuteWithCircuitBreaker<T>(Func<Task<T>> func)
        {
            if (!_circuitBreakerStateManager.IsInState(CircuitBreakerState.Closed))
            {
                if (HalfOpen())
                {
                    bool lockTaken = false;
                    try
                    {
                        Monitor.TryEnter(_halfOpenSyncObject, ref lockTaken);
                        if (lockTaken)
                        {
                            var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(_options.ActionTimeout);
                            var resultTask = func.Invoke();

                            var firstFinishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(timeoutTask, resultTask);
                            if (firstFinishedTask == timeoutTask)
                            {
                                throw new TimeoutException($"Operation reached timeout configured for this circuit breaker. Timeout: {_options.ActionTimeout.TotalSeconds} s");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Reset();
                                return await resultTask;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Trip(ex);
                        throw;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (lockTaken)
                        {
                            Monitor.Exit(_halfOpenSyncObject);
                        }
                    }
                }
                throw new CircuitBreakerOpenException(_circuitBreakerStateManager.LastException);
            }

            // Circuit Breaker is closed - execute function normally
            try
            {
                var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(_options.ActionTimeout);
                var resultTask = func.Invoke();
                var firstFinishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(timeoutTask, resultTask);
                if (firstFinishedTask == timeoutTask)
                    throw new TimeoutException($"Operation reached timeout configured for this circuit breaker. Timeout: {_options.ActionTimeout.TotalSeconds} s");             
                else
                    return await resultTask;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Trip(ex);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

As you can see in above snippet TryEnter is wrapped in Try/Finally which ensures lock will be released no matter what. The problem, I am having is that at some point `Monitor.TryEnter` starts to return false for every attemp. I debugged the code and found that before it starts happening, for every `Monitor.TryEnter` call, `Monitor.Exit` is executed - meaning the lock should be released, but it seems not as at this point every call returns false. Not sure how this is possible.

Is it possible that `Monitor.Exit` doesn't release the lock because of some reason ( it does not throw any exception though ) ? Or maybe i'm doing something wrong in here ?

EDIT. This is how _halfOpenSyncObject is declared ( there is only one instance of this class )

```
public class TimeoutableCircuitBreaker: ICircuitBreaker
{
    private readonly object _halfOpenSyncObject = new object();    
    ...
```

EDIT HalfOpen implementation:

```
private bool HalfOpen()
        {
            var isHalfOpen = _circuitBreakerStateManager.GetLastStateChangedDate() + _options.BreakDuration < DateTime.UtcNow;
            if (isHalfOpen)
                _circuitBreakerStateManager.SetState(CircuitBreakerState.HalfOpen);
            return isHalfOpen;
        }
```

Comment: I'm very concerned by the use of this in async code. Unless you have a single-thread synchronization context in *every* place you call this, you could end up calling Monitor.Exit from a different thread than the one that calls Monitor.TryEnter. Generally speaking, locks and async don't go well together.

Comment: @mjwills sorry i added that after i made some reading it might help, but generally it's not there

Comment: @JonSkeet could you explain in what circumstances "Monitor.Exit" could be called from different thread than Monitor.TryEnter" ? It's a part of one function call, none of those calls wrapped in thead/task - i was not aware something like that can happen

Comment: If instead of  `Monitor.TryEnter` you tried to use `lock ()` statement - compiler would emit an error "await cannot be used in lock body", and you would have avoided this problem.

Comment: For async locks avoiding `Monitor` you have options from [Stephen Cleary](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncLock), [Stephen Toub](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/02/12/building-async-coordination-primitives-part-6-asynclock/) and [Bar Arnon](http://blog.i3arnon.com/2018/02/05/async-utilities/#async-lock).

Comment: You're using async/await. The code that executes after an `await` operator may very well be on a different thread than the code that executes before it, unless you're in a single-thread synchronization context.

Comment: @JonSkeet I understand but I think if this would happen - Monitor.Exit would throw SynchronizationLockException, but it does not in my case. Exit call does not throw any exceptions

Comment: Anyway thanks everyone. I guess i have to re-write it to non-async code. I'll refactor and update the question with the results soon

Comment: Instead of rewriting to non-async - better use one of the async locks mentioned in comment above.

Comment: @MajkeloDev: Are you sure that `Monitor.Exit` isn't throwing, rather than just that you're not *seeing* the exception? But yes, I would expect it to throw too.

Comment: @JonSkeet placed a try catch on exit function. You were right - it throws that exception.

Comment: @Evk looking at these - none of them seems to support the same funcionality ( try to get a lock -> if fail to acquire lock don't wait just execute different code )

Comment: @Evk ok i can see i can use SemaphoreSlim.Wait(Timespan) which returns bool. Thanks

Comment: @MajkeloDev Finally, although this doesn't further learning about async locks, you have the option of off-the-shelf circuit-breaker and timeout policies from libraries like [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly#resilience-policies).  Polly [uses `Interlocked` internally](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/27e1a83bbdd3542902f654fec1e474d01f15d815/src/Polly.Shared/CircuitBreaker/CircuitStateController.cs#L140) to ensure only one thread wins the race to run a single trial execution, in half-open state. [disclosure: I maintain Polly]